# Getting the path for .NET Core runtime Dlls

Tags: .net-core, .net-assembly

I inspect .NET dlls with the MetaLoadContext, introduced in .NET core 3.0.

Since the MetaLoadContext needs an assembly resolver (e.g. the provided PathAssemblyResolver) , I want to create an own one which has the strategy that it loads the .NET runtime DLL (e.g. netstandard.dll) from the SDK installation path. The issue is how can I get programmatically the SDK installation path with the runtime DLLs ?

Answer (score 2):

To get the path of the runtime .NET core DLLs call

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory()
```